# How do I make my JAVA-application only affect a single screen?

Tags: java, libgdx, screen

It actually only runs on one screen. But to my annoyance **the other screen turns black**, I would like to have it unaffected so that I can see stuff on it during development.

**NOTE:** My application is based on the **libGDX framework**.

DesktopLauncher

```
public static void main (String[] arg)
{
    // Build Texture Atlases
    if (rebuildAtlas) {
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        settings.maxWidth = 1024;
        settings.maxHeight = 1024;
        settings.combineSubdirectories = true;

        // Pack images in "textures" folder
        TexturePacker.process("assets/textures", "assets/atlas", "textures.atlas");
    }   
    
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

    cfg.title = "LoA";
    cfg.useGL30 = false;
    cfg.width = Cn.RESOLUTION_WIDTH;
    cfg.height = Cn.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT;
    cfg.fullscreen = true;
    
    new LwjglApplication(new LoA(), cfg);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should look at the libGDX documentation then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `fullscreen = true`.

*Fullscreen* means that the normal desktop is replaced by a new separate desktop dedicated to the program, and the desktop covers all screens.

You need to run in *Windowed* mode, with a window that is maximized to one screen, so the other screen still shows the original desktop.

Lots of games have the Fullscreen vs Windowed mode option, in case you want to see it in effect.

Comment: Thank you, works fine now. For others reading this: If you also want to get rid of the window border, use: **System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");**